# How to send html gmail message through javascript gapi?

Tags: javascript, html, gmail, google-api-js-client

I am trying to send email message using JavaScript Gmail API, but I cannot find how to do it.

Well, I have code to send normal email message, but all html is displayed  like text.

Here is code:

```
var email = "From: me\r\nTo: "+to+ "\r\nBcc: " +bcc+ "\r\nSubject: "+subject+"\r\n\r\nbody: " + content;
```

SEND MESSAGE WITH METADATA ONLY

```
function sendMessage(email,id) 
{
    var base64EncodedEmail = btoa(unescape(encodeURIComponent(email))).replace(/\//g,'_').replace(/\+/g,'-');
    var request = gapi.client.gmail.users.messages.send({
                                                        'userId': 'me',
                                                        'resource': {
                                                                    'raw':    base64EncodedEmail
                                                                   }, 


                                                      });
    request.execute(callbacksend);
}
```

When I have tried to set content type as html in response, I receieved an error response from server that I need to use upload method.

Indeed, here - https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/send

Is said:
Upload URI, for media upload requests:

POST https://www.googleapis.com/upload/gmail/v1/users/userId/messages/send

but while trying to use 
    gapi.client.load('upload', 'v1', callback);
or just trying to run `gapi.client.upload.gmail.users.messages.send`
its not found...

I have no idea how to perform such request, or another way to send html message from gmail. Perhaps  I need to try it from pure XMLHttprequest, but better to find the way to perform it from gapi.

p.s I've made such request through google apps script:

```
GmailApp.sendEmail(<recipient>,'subject', <message>,{htmlBody:<message>, bcc:'test@gmail.com'});
```

But need to perform it with javascript.

Thanks!

Comment: Did you get an answer to this?